# Connection refused when connecting from docker container to a service on a host running the container

Tags: docker, nginx, centos, centos7

I'm running a docker container and a .NET Core service on Centos 7. I use the following `Dockerfile` to generate my container (Angular app):

```
FROM node:11-alpine as builder
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app
WORKDIR /ng-app
COPY . .
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I build the image with:

```
docker build -t myservice .
```

And run container with:

```
docker run -d -it --name=msrv --net=host myservice
```

`netstat -plntu` run on the server has the following two lines which are of interest here (when container is running):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1469/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2936/dotnet
```

The .NET Core service is accessible via the public address of the server. With `--net=host` option I thought that the app running in my container should be able to connect to the service using the address `http://localhost:5000/api/webtoken` (to get the security token on login) but I get `net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when I try to access it. I can get the token just fine when I use Postman.

Everything seems to be in order, but I can't connect from container to the dotnet service. What am I doing wrong?

In case it might help, here is the `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  set $backend_addr http://localhost:5000;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass $backend_addr;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```